# PLSQL function returns a clob but it's unclear if it is being freed implicitly or automaticly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am very new to PLSQL.

However, I am working with the CLOB datatype. I've heard that it is easy to create memory leaks with CLOBs?

Here is a function I created that simply selects data from a table and puts it into the CLOB. Is there anything else I need to do to ensure my memory is being managed properly?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLastGPoverPeriod
RETURN clob IS
    stuff clob;
BEGIN 
   SELECT NAME INTO stuff 
   FROM TEMP;
   dbms_output.put_line(stuff);

   RETURN stuff; 
END;
/
```

Comment: yes, return type should be clob and not varchar2, output could be a problem.

Comment: I don't see the need for the following line in your function: `dbms_output.put_line(stuff);
` Can you explain why you require this?

Comment: it's just to test that the information is being queried successfully. Its debugging stuff. It's the equivalent of `console.log` in javascript or `cout <<` in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.  Resources used by an anonymous block are automatically cleaned out when the anonymous block is complete (except for things like uncommitted transactions).  I've never seen memory leaks caused by CLOBs.

Although there are some potential space issues with large CLOBs.  CLOBs can be stored in temporary tablespace, which is a finite resource and not always sized properly.  .  But reading a single CLOB at a time shouldn't be a problem, unless it's a multi-gigabyte file.